# Copy Worksheet Object Defined Error in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I see this issue has come up a handful of times on this forum however none of the solutions have helped me. The code below actually did work, but then it started throwing an application-defined or objected defined error and now will not work. The code runs from within an Excel template, opens up each Excel report in the directory, then pastes 2 worksheets into the document.

```
Sub updateED()

Dim pathout, pathin As String
Dim WbOutput As Workbook
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(filepath)

'step through each xls file
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If InStr(objFile, ".xls") Then

            Set WbOutput = Workbooks.Open(objFile)

            Application.DisplayAlerts = False

            'drop in additional templates
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Business Entity", "Facility")).Copy before:=WbOutput.Sheets("Mbr_Detail_ED")

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't tell, as the formatting is funky, but just FYI you can't do multiple 'dim' statements on the same line.  (`Dim pathout, pathin as String, dim WbOutput ...`) should just be `Dim pathout, pathin as String, WbOutput as Workbook, objFSO as Object, ...`.  Also, where does it throw that error? On the .copy line?

Comment: You should explicitly declare the variable types.  Using `Dim pathout, pathin as String` will result in `pathin` being a String, but `pathout` being a Variant.  You should do `Dim pathout as String, pathin As String` instead.  Variants are slower and use more memory and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: What line has the error?  The code to copy looks correct.  It is possible the workbook is not opening correctly. I assume your sheet names exist.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```
Option Explicit
Sub updateED()
Dim Pathout As String
Dim Pathin As String
Dim WbOutput As Workbook
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Temp\")

'step through each xls file
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If InStr(objFile, ".xls") Then

            Set WbOutput = Workbooks.Open(objFile)

            Application.DisplayAlerts = False

            'drop in additional templates
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Business Entity", "Facility")).Copy before:=WbOutput.Sheets("Mbr_Detail_ED")

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```